# Parsing twitter json response

Tags: twitter, json

I've made a twitter api request (GET trends/place API) and the result is just like this:

```
[{"trends":[{"name":"#BabyIsStaying","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23BabyIsStaying","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23BabyIsStaying","events":null},{"name":"#AkTakipBa\u015fl\u0131yor","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23AkTakipBa%C5%9Fl%C4%B1yor","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23AkTakipBa%C5%9Fl%C4%B1yor","events":null},{"name":"#\u00c7apulcuTakip","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23%C3%87apulcuTakip","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23%C3%87apulcuTakip","events":null},{"name":"#SadeceKar\u015f\u0131l\u0131kl\u0131Takiple\u015fme","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23SadeceKar%C5%9F%C4%B1l%C4%B1kl%C4%B1Takiple%C5%9Fme","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23SadeceKar%C5%9F%C4%B1l%C4%B1kl%C4%B1Takiple%C5%9Fme","events":null},{"name":"#soysuzek\u015fis\u00f6zl\u00fck","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%23soysuzek%C5%9Fis%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk","promoted_content":null,"query":"%23soysuzek%C5%9Fis%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk","events":null},{"name":"B\u00fcy\u00fck FENERBAH\u00c7E Taraftarlar\u0131Takiple\u015fiyor","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22B%C3%BCy%C3%BCk+FENERBAH%C3%87E+Taraftarlar%C4%B1Takiple%C5%9Fiyor%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22B%C3%BCy%C3%BCk+FENERBAH%C3%87E+Taraftarlar%C4%B1Takiple%C5%9Fiyor%22","events":null},{"name":"Sar\u0131K\u0131rm\u0131z\u0131Aile UnfollowsuzTakiple\u015fiyor","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22Sar%C4%B1K%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1Aile+UnfollowsuzTakiple%C5%9Fiyor%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22Sar%C4%B1K%C4%B1rm%C4%B1z%C4%B1Aile+UnfollowsuzTakiple%C5%9Fiyor%22","events":null},{"name":"D\u00fcnyadaTeksinSen GALATASARAY\u0131m","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22D%C3%BCnyadaTeksinSen+GALATASARAY%C4%B1m%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22D%C3%BCnyadaTeksinSen+GALATASARAY%C4%B1m%22","events":null},{"name":"D\u00fcnyan\u0131n TekHarikas\u0131s\u0131n FENERBAH\u00c7EM","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22D%C3%BCnyan%C4%B1n+TekHarikas%C4%B1s%C4%B1n+FENERBAH%C3%87EM%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22D%C3%BCnyan%C4%B1n+TekHarikas%C4%B1s%C4%B1n+FENERBAH%C3%87EM%22","events":null},{"name":"MustafaKemalin\u0130zindeyiz \u00c7\u00fcnk\u00fcFenerbah\u00e7eliyiz","url":"http:\/\/twitter.com\/search?q=%22MustafaKemalin%C4%B0zindeyiz+%C3%87%C3%BCnk%C3%BCFenerbah%C3%A7eliyiz%22","promoted_content":null,"query":"%22MustafaKemalin%C4%B0zindeyiz+%C3%87%C3%BCnk%C3%BCFenerbah%C3%A7eliyiz%22","events":null}],"as_of":"2013-07-20T10:51:45Z","created_at":"2013-07-20T10:45:24Z","locations":[{"name":"Turkey","woeid":23424969}]}]
```

My question is how to turn this array string into html. No proper php experience at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response you are getting is JSON.

You *used* to be able to get response in XML, RSS and more, but now the only response type you will receive is JSON.

PHP has multiple methods for dealing with JSON. To encode data, you would use `json_encode()`. However, you want to *decode* it, so you want to be doing the following:

```
var_dump(json_decode($yourData));
```

This will dump the data to the browser so you can see what you have to work with.

You can iterate around this data using a `foreach()` loop.

Remember, assuming you `json_decode()` your results into `$yourData`:

- To access array properties, use: `$yourData['propertyName']`
- To access object properties, use: `$yourData->propertyName`

Answer (score 0):

you can feed that into [json_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function
you will get an array that you can manage as you want.